error when I access in debug mode in the products section

Exceptions 2

Logs 2

Stack Traces 2


PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Exception\CoreException
in [classes/]**[Hook.php](line 434)

            // Exceptions that implements ModuleErrorInterface are usefull to display error messages

            throw $e;

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $environment = ServiceLocator::get('\\PrestaShop\\PrestaShop\\Adapter\\Environment');

            if ($environment->isDebug()) {

                throw new CoreException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);

            }

        }


        return '';

    }


HookCore::callHookOn()in [Hook.php](line 986)

                // we will pass the response from the previous one as parameters.

                if (0 !== $key && true === $chain) {

                    $hook_args = $output;

                }


                $display = Hook::callHookOn($moduleInstance, $registeredHookName, $hook_args);


                // Case 1 - each module response to different array key. We don't care about the response.

                if ($array_return) {

                    $output[$moduleInstance->name] = $display;

                // Case 2 - chaining. Here, each module MUST return an array that will the next module receive as parameters.


HookCore::exec()in [modules/ets_superspeed/classes/ext/] modules/ets_superspeed/classes/ext/ets_hook&line=224#line224)(line 224)

            return;

        }

        $ajax = self::isAjax();

        $page_cache =  self::_checkPageNoCache() ? false :true;

        if((!$page_cache && !Configuration::get('ETS_SPEED_RECORD_MODULE_PERFORMANCE')) || $ajax )

            return HookCore::exec($hook_name,$hook_args,$id_module,$array_return,$check_exceptions,$use_push,$id_shop,$chain);

        $controller = Context::getContext()->controller;

        if(!isset($controller->controller_type) || ($controller->controller_type!='modulefront' && $controller->controller_type!='front'))

            return HookCore::exec($hook_name,$hook_args,$id_module,$array_return,$check_exceptions,$use_push,$id_shop,$chain);

        $hook = new HookCore();

        if(method_exists($hook,'getHookRegistry'))


Ets_Hook::exec17()in [override/classes/][Hook.php](line 37)

        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../modules/ets_superspeed/classes/ext/ets_hook');

        $class='Ets_Hook';

        $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1);

        if (Tools::version_compare(_PS_VERSION_,'1.7','>=')) {

            $method='exec17';

            return call_user_func_array(array($class, $method),array($hook_name,$hook_args,$id_module,$array_return,$check_exceptions,$use_push,$id_shop,$chain,$backtrace));

        }

        else

        {

            $method='exec16';

            return call_user_func_array(array($class, $method),array($hook_name,$hook_args,$id_module,$array_return,$check_exceptions,$use_push,$id_shop));


Hook::exec()**[LegacyHookSubscriber.php](line 123)

        }


        $moduleId = (int) $ids[1];

        list($event, $hookName) = $args;


        $content = Hook::exec(

            $hookName,

            $event->getHookParameters(),

            $moduleId,

            ($event instanceof RenderingHookEvent)

        );


LegacyHookSubscriber->****[HookDispatcher.php](line 179)

    protected function doDispatch($listeners, $eventName, Event $event)

    {

        foreach ($listeners as $listener) {

            // removes $this to parameters. Hooks should not have access to dispatcher

            ob_start();

            $listener($event, $eventName, null);

            $obContent = ob_get_clean();


            if ($event instanceof RenderingHookEvent) {

                $listenerName = $event->popListener() ?: $listener[1];



HookDispatcher->doDispatch()in [src/Adapter/Hook/]**[HookDispatcher.php](line 113)

        if (!$event instanceof HookEvent) {

            throw new \Exception('HookDispatcher must dispatch a HookEvent subclass only. ' . get_class($event) . ' given.');

        }


        if ($listeners = $this->getListeners(strtolower($eventName))) {

            $this->doDispatch($listeners, $eventName, $event);

        } elseif ($this->isDebug && null !== $this->hookRegistry) {

            // When a hook has no listeners it means it's not even in the database or no modules were attached, in the current case

            // Hook::exec will never be called meaning no stats will be registered for this hook So we handle the registry data collection

            // here so that we can still get some info in the Debug toolbar

            $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 5);


HookDispatcher->dispatch()in **[HookDispatcher.php](line 228)

    {

        $event = new RenderingHookEvent($this->getHookEventContextParameters());

        $event->setHookParameters($parameters);


        /** @var RenderingHookEvent $eventDispatched */

        $eventDispatched = $this->dispatch($eventName, $event);


        return $eventDispatched;

    }


    /**


HookDispatcher->renderForParameters()in **[HookDispatcher.php](line 75)

    /**

     * {@inheritdoc}

     */

    public function dispatchRendering(HookInterface $hook)

    {

        $event = $this->hookDispatcherAdapter->renderForParameters(

            $hook->getName(),

            $hook->getParameters()

        );


        $content = $event->getContent();


HookDispatcher->dispatchRendering()in [src/Core/Hook/])**[HookDispatcher.php](line 93)

    /**

     * {@inheritdoc}

     */

    public function dispatchRenderingWithParameters($hookName, array $hookParameters = [])

    {

        return $this->dispatchRendering(new Hook($hookName, $hookParameters));

    }


    /**

     * {@inheritdoc}

     */


HookDispatcher->dispatchRenderingWithParameters()in [src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Sell/Product/]**[ExtraModulesType.php](line 113)

    protected function renderHooksArray(int $productId): array

    {

        // The call to the render of the hooks is encapsulated into a ob management to avoid any call of echo from the

        // modules.

        ob_start();

        $renderedHook = $this->hookDispatcher->dispatchRenderingWithParameters(

            self::HOOK_NAME,

            [

                'id_product' => $productId,

            ]

        );


ExtraModulesType->renderHooksArray()in [src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Sell/Product/]**[ExtraModulesType.php](line 83)

     */

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)

    {

        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);


        $extraModules = $this->renderHooksArray($options['product_id']);

        $view->vars['extraModules'] = $extraModules;

    }


    /**

     * {@inheritDoc}


in [vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/]> buildView (line 147)

    {

        if (null !== $this->parent) {

            $this->parent->buildView($view, $form, $options);

        }


        $this->innerType->buildView($view, $form, $options);


        foreach ($this->typeExtensions as $extension) {

            $extension->buildView($view, $form, $options);

        }

    }


in [vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/DataCollector/Proxy/] **[ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php] buildView (line 103)

    /**

     * {@inheritdoc}

     */

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)

    {

        $this->proxiedType->buildView($view, $form, $options);

    }


    /**

     * {@inheritdoc}

     */


in [vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/]**[Form.php]> buildView (line 1055)
**[Form.php]-> createView (line 1058)
Form->createView()in [src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/Sell/Catalog/Product/]**[ProductController.php](line 1113)
ErrorException
Warning: Undefined array key "link"
I'm doing tests and I can't get anything

As indicated in the stack trace, this is a problem generated from an override file from the "ets_superspeed" module.
You will have to contact the developers for assistance.

Welcome to SO ! Please see: Editing Help to improve your question.
